# BETWEEN months query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get rows witch has a season start date and season end date in current date. 
But I have problem with periods between months in winter. For example winter starts 01.11 and end at 28.02 (I don't care about 27 or 28)

When I try to get products in winter like below query

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN seasons S ON P.s_id = S.id
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEENS MONTH(S.startdate) and MONTH(S.enddate)
```

I get nothing

The table `seasons` has one row with below value

```
id = 1
Description = Winter
startdate = 2013-11-01
enddate = 2014-02-28
```

!IMPORTANT
I don;t care about `year`

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: TWO diffrent datatypes! INT and date

Comment: Sorry you are right. I will edit my question

Comment: But shouldn't the enddate be in 2014?

Comment: The solution here is to care about year. How can you have an end date with an earlier date than start date? Maybe you want to compare `enddate - startdate` then?

Comment: No. I want compare Current Date with startdate and enddate. Let say that I will change enddate year to 2014 (actualy next year of start date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a CASE:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN seasons S ON P.s_id = S.id
WHERE CASE 
WHEN MONTH(S.startdate) > MONTH(S.enddate)
  AND (MONTH(CURDATE()) > MONTH(S.startdate) 
      OR MONTH(CURDATE()) < MONTH(S.enddate))
  THEN 1
WHEN MONTH(S.startdate) <= MONTH(S.enddate)
  AND MONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN MONTH(S.startdate) AND MONTH(S.enddate)
  THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

This assumes that whenever MONTH(startdate) > MONTH(enddate) the year has changed.
Will return true in that case whenever MONTH(curdate()) is bigger than MONTH(startdate) OR is smaller than MONTH(enddate).

In the case when MONTH(startdate) <= MONTH(enddate) it just validates if it is between them.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6241/3)</kbd>

Comment: What if the month of the start date is 11 and month of the start date is 2 ... `BETWEEN 11 AND 2` eh?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO. when he says he doesn't care about YEAR, i didn't even though of that possibility, but that's a good point

Comment: @ZalonisAntonis. I constructed a little experiment to try to fix it. See if it works for you

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO. I tried a little experiment to fix that issue when startdate is 11 and end date is 2

Comment: I accepted your answer because your code is better from mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you get anything? You're doing the equivalent of

```
WHERE 5 BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

You're doing a literal apples/oranges comparison. Perhaps you want

```
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN MONTH(S.startdate) AND MONTH(S.enddate)
```

instead, so you're doing apples to apples.

Comment: If start date month is 11 and end date month is 2, `BETWEEN 11 AND 2` won't work.

Comment: Yeaeh: missmatch in datatypes

Comment: exactly @FreshPrinceOfSO  The question is how can make to work??

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with start date being after end date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the strange converting to strings and parsing solutions. You can do this with a little math...

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN seasons S ON P.s_id = S.id
WHERE ((DAYOFYEAR(CurDate()) - DAYOFYEAR(S.startdate)) + 365) % 365 BETWEEN 0 AND 
    (((DAYOFYEAR(S.enddate) + 365) - DAYOFYEAR(S.startdate))) % 365
```

Comment: What trying to do with your code? i don't understand. if you have a startdate 2013-06-01 and enddate 2013-08-31 it will works?

Comment: That's the idea. It should do a wrap around comparison on the dates. It's a little messy with the +365 as MySQL mod returns -ve for -ve numbers. One thing to note however, this does not account for leap years!

Comment: With below code works too 
 
SELECT 
 ((DAYOFYEAR('2015-12-04') - DAYOFYEAR('2014-06-01')) + 365) % 365 BETWEEN 0 AND 
    (((DAYOFYEAR('2013-08-31') + 365) - DAYOFYEAR('2014-06-01'))) % 365

Comment: Yes. Years are ignored as per your question. If you are not sure what its doing: It's repositioning the year to start with your start date at day 0. That's why between has 0, and "days after start date".

Answer (score 0):

Between requires the values be in order - your start date is AFTER your end date so you'll always get nothing.

Additionally, you are comparing months to dates; since the date has the year in it you can't ignore the year that way.

You have to compare the day in year to ignore the year. If DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) is between DAYOFYEAR(end date) and DAYOFYEAR(start date) that will work if both end data and start date are in the same year. You'll need to get a bit fancier if they are in different years, but that should be obvious.

Also, you probably have to think through what "not caring about year" really means. If you're looking for dates between March and September, that will be the reverse of looking for dates between September and March. What you want will alter how you program it.

Comment: @stv - yes, perhaps. I can't tell what the OP is trying to do. If the start date and end date can be in the order he says, he really wants to leave out the year from the start date and end date. But I'm guessing.

Comment: "not caring about year" means: startdate = WHATEVER YEAR-11-01
enddate = SAME OR NEXT YEAR-02-28

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
SELECT *

FROM products P
LEFT JOIN seasons S ON P.s_id = S.id

WHERE 

IF(
 ( CURDATE() BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(S.startdate),'-',DAY(S.startdate)) , '%Y-%m-%d')  AND STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( IF( MONTH(S.`enddate`) < MONTH(S.`startdate`) ,YEAR(CURDATE())+1,YEAR(CURDATE()) ),'-',MONTH(s.`enddate`),'-',DAY(S.`enddate`)) , '%Y-%m-%d')  ),

"IN Season", 
 IF( P.`s_id` IS NOT NULL AND P.`s_id` != "","Out OF Season","" )
) = "IN Season"
```

I have 2 rows 
1. Startdate: 2013-11-01 EndDate: 2014-02-28 (Winter) 
2. StartDate: 2013-06-01 ENDDate: 2013-08-31 (Summer)

It works perfect.